# How to make a type definition file available for multiple occurrences of a JS file in different folders?

Tags: typescript

In a project a JS file is generated and I wrote a type definition file for it, which works well, when the d.ts files is in the same folder as the generated JS file.

Now I changed the project to create two different incarnations of that JS file (release and debug) in different subfolders. The type definition file is the same for both, of course, and located in the parent dir, like this:

```bash
src/
    test.ts
wasm/
    debug/
        antlr4-runtime-wasm.js
    release/
        antlr4-runtime-wasm.js
    antlr4-runtime-wasm.d.ts
```

With this setup the typescript compiler doesn't find the type definitions for the JS file, when importing it like:

`import Module, { ANTLR4Wasm, Vector } from "../wasm/release/antlr4-runtime-wasm.js";`

I tried adding the a `typeRoots` field in tsconfig.json, added the d.ts file to the `include` section, tried a reference import in the test.ts file and also played with the `path` setting in tsconfig.json. Nothing worked for me. I always get:

> Could not find a declaration file for module '../wasm/release/antlr4-runtime-wasm.js'. '/Volumes/Extern/Work/projects/antlr4wasm/wasm/release/antlr4-runtime-wasm.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. ts(7016)

I can of course move the d.ts file to the release/ folder and add a copy of it to the debug/ folder, but that's obviously not a good solution.

How can I make this scenario work?

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript compiler uses a specific resolution logic to find type declaration (.d.ts) files for a given module. The structure you've described is not typical, and therefore, TypeScript's default resolution mechanism struggles with it.

One solution is to use module augmentation and path aliases in your tsconfig.json to map the runtime path to your type definition.

Here's how you can achieve this:

1. Modify your tsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... other options ...

    "baseUrl": "./",  // this must be specified if paths are used
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/types/*"],  // assuming your actual types are in `src/types`
      "../wasm/release/antlr4-runtime-wasm.js": ["wasm/antlr4-runtime-wasm.d.ts"],
      "../wasm/debug/antlr4-runtime-wasm.js": ["wasm/antlr4-runtime-wasm.d.ts"]
    }
  },

  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

- In your wasm/antlr4-runtime-wasm.d.ts:

```js
declare module '../wasm/release/antlr4-runtime-wasm.js' {
    // ... your existing type definitions ...
}

declare module '../wasm/debug/antlr4-runtime-wasm.js' {
    // ... your existing type definitions ...
}
```

The key idea is to declare the modules with the exact relative paths TypeScript will use when resolving the module. This explicitly maps the .js files to their corresponding .d.ts files.

With this setup, TypeScript should correctly associate the type definition with both JS files, regardless of where they're imported from in your project.

Comment: I already tried many variations of the `path` setting, to no avail. Additionally, your suggestion to change the typings file and adding module declarations would require a duplication (and a maintenance nightmare) of the definitions.